# Simple script is working in Python console but gets error in Script Editor (PyQGIS)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

This simple script retrieving a value of raster pixel size works in Python console, but can't be processed in Script editor: "No script found. Seems there is no valid script in the file."
How could it be solved?

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer

ras = QgsRasterLayer(r"C:\Users\123\123.tif")
pixelsizeX = ras.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelsizeY = ras.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
print (pixelsizeX)
print (pixelsizeY)
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: This is not a valid processing script. Start your learning journey [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html). And pay attention to the tip [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#flags)

Comment: Also check out: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_python_scripts.html and: https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-writing-a-processing-script/

Answer (score 1):

That may be a valid pyqgis script, but it's not a valid [processing script](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html). You can run it from the [console script editor](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/python_console.html#the-code-editor), not the processing script editor.

[image]